# Unity3D 2D game. Fit camera horizontally

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I'm working on Unity3D 2D mobile game and I've got a problem connected with aspect ratio. When changing aspect ratio the camera always fits vertically. For landscape mode games it is a good practice. For portrait mode games it is better to fit camera horizontally. So My game needs to fit camera horizontally. Please help me with it.

Comment: fits vertically to what?

Comment: Here is what I need. The with of the camera to be unchanged, but the height to be changed depending on aspect ratio of the device

Comment: Just multiply your width by a constant aspect ratio to get your height then

Comment: How would I do that. Could you please explain

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your aspect ratio is `4:3`

If you want to make your camera fit landscape mode of 16 units wide, you would make your camera a size of `16 / 4 * 4`

If you want to make your camera fit portrait mode of 16 units tall, you would make your camera a size of `16 / 3 * 4`